# TypeError: analyzers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting the following error when trying to execute publicly available code (lines 200-205 "Features Drift" section) from https://github.com/evidentlyai/evidently/blob/main/evidently/tutorials/historical_drift_visualization.ipynb:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-0cdbc9afe012> in <module>
      3 
      4 for date in experiment_batches:
----> 5     drifts = detect_features_drift(raw_data.loc[reference_dates[0]:reference_dates[1]], 
      6                            raw_data.loc[date[0]:date[1]],
      7                            column_mapping=data_columns,

<ipython-input-16-044c700989fb> in detect_features_drift(reference, production, column_mapping, confidence, threshold, get_pvalues)
      8     """
      9 
---> 10     data_drift_profile = Profile(sections=[DataDriftProfileSection])
     11     data_drift_profile.calculate(reference, production, column_mapping=column_mapping)
     12     report = data_drift_profile.json()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\evidently\model_profile\model_profile.py in __init__(self, sections, options)
     16 
     17     def __init__(self, sections: Sequence[ProfileSection], options: Optional[list] = None):
---> 18         super().__init__(sections, options if options is not None else [])
     19         self.result = {}
     20 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\evidently\pipeline\pipeline.py in __init__(self, stages, options)
     20         self.analyzers_results = {}
     21         self.options_provider = OptionsProvider()
---> 22         self._analyzers = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([stage.analyzers() for stage in stages]))
     23         for option in options:
     24             self.options_provider.add(option)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\evidently\pipeline\pipeline.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     20         self.analyzers_results = {}
     21         self.options_provider = OptionsProvider()
---> 22         self._analyzers = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([stage.analyzers() for stage in stages]))
     23         for option in options:
     24             self.options_provider.add(option)

TypeError: analyzers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I obtained a similar error after trying to execute lines 195-196 (section: Dataset drift).

I use Python 3.8.8.

I installed Evidently with some problems. After successful installation (`pip install --user Evidently`) I got the following error:

> mitosheet 0.1.361 requires plotly==5.3.0, but you have plotly 4.12.0 which is incompatible

and after `(pip install plotly==5.3.0)` pip informed me that

> 0.1.34.dev0 requires plotly~=4.12.0, but you have plotly 5.3.0 which is incompatible.

Comment: The pip installation with user argument seems to be contradictory with a tip from the "evidently" team: "building reports inside a Jupyter notebook is not yet possible for Windows. The reason is Windows requires administrator privileges to create symlink."

Comment: The code was fixed by the developer, see  "Fixed historical_drift_visualization.ipynb tutorial" at github.com/evidentlyai/evidently/tree/main/evidently/tutorials Now, the code generates the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add parenthesis in front of it.

For example:

```
data_and_target_drift_report = Dashboard(tabs=[DataDriftTab(),CatTargetDriftTab()])
```